# Button to not run script

Tags: button

I'm looking to have a button that, when pressed down, will mean that the script loaded on the Arduino doesn't run. So far I have:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(3, INPUT_PULLUP);
  if (digitalRead(3) == LOW) {
    while(1);
  }
  // Beginning the Keyboard stream
  Keyboard.begin();
  // then the rest of the code.
```

I have a push button soldered to the ground and 3 pin. Could you see what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Well the while(1); will mean that the code will stop cold. Even if you release the button, the code will not resume.

Comment: @AndreCourchesne Since that code is in `setup()` it will only get called if the button is closed when the Arduino starts up.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp true indeed.

Comment: aside: compiled code is not a "script"...

Comment: Welcome to Arduino SE.  Be sure to take the tour to see how things work here:  https://arduino.stackexchange.com/Tour

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
void setup () {
    pinMode(3, INPUT_PULLUP);
}
void loop () {
    while (digitalRead(3)==LOW) {}; //do nothing, wait for release button
    // do all my stuff
}
```

or even better I would use some LED to indicate, that the button is pressed (or released) to have some visual state indicator (or another stuff to do while the button is pressed

```
void setup () {
    pinMode(3, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(13,LOW);
}
void loop () {
    while (digitalRead(3)==LOW) {
       digitalWrite(13,HIGH); // let it shine
       };
    digitalWrite(13,LOW);
    // do all my stuff
}
```

eventually

```
void setup () {
    pinMode(3, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(13,LOW);
}
void loop () {
    if (digitalRead(3)==LOW) {
       digitalWrite(13,HIGH); // let it shine
       while (digitalRead(3)==LOW) {
          // do some other stuff
       };
    digitalWrite(13,LOW); // switch indicator off
    // do my regular stuff
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to move the code that checks the button into `loop()`. Put the code that you want to pause in the `if` block.

```
void loop() {
    // Only execute if not pressed
    if (digitalRead(3) != LOW) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```